# Android bindService / remote services - any basic examples?

Tags: android, service

As a newbie to Android development, I'm trying to do the basics and build a media player. It works fine in one activity, but I'm now moving the MediaPlayer stuff to a remote service so it can carry on after the activity is destroy. I've moved the necessary code to the service, left comments in the activity where I'll need to call service methods, implemented my AIDL and it all builds with no errors (Eclipse).

However, I'm totally stumped as to how to call IPC methods. Are there any simple and minimal examples with no fat - just the bare essentials?

As I'm using IPC methods, I don't need to use onStart() at all - right? (I intend to use LoadFile(File path), and then have public void considerDeath() { if (!isPlaying()) { MyService.stopSelf(); } } method called from activity.onDestroy )

/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html has multiple binders, but when I use the mSecondaryConnection portion, I get "**MyService.Stub cannot be resolved**"

I've tried http://www.anddev.org/remote_service_tutorial-t8127.html which seems to confuse things by overloading methods.

I can't find anything by Mark Murphy either on the subject :(

Comment: You do not want to use a remote service for this scenario. Your service can live on after the activities are destroyed. Just use startService() to start up the service, and do not call stopService() until the user presses the stop button. A remote service will just use excess memory for no added value.

Comment: BTW, for remote service examples, check out http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices/

Comment: Thanks. Would a local service really work for the following scenario?

* User loads activity and selects file to play
* Whilst listening to the file, the user presses 'back' on their device and goes to check their mail, write an SMS and browse the net. All the while the file plays. Android probably decides to destroy my activity.
* The user decides to go back to the app, pause the currently playing file and load a different file.

Comment: Can the new instance of my app interface with the local service which is already running? If so, startService()/stopService() definitely makes sense. Although I still need AIDL to call myService.pause(), and myService.skipToPosition(long milliseconds) - right?

Comment: "Would a local service really work for the following scenario?" Sure -- what you are describing is the behavior of the built-in Media Player, for example. "Can the new instance of my app interface with the local service which is already running?" It won't be a new instance of your app. It will be a new instance of your activity, running in the same process as your local service. "I still need AIDL to call myService.pause()..." No. AIDL is only for remote services. Use the local binding pattern to get the service object and just call methods on it. And feel free to start a new SO question!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

minicompact.com/mobiletalk/?p=18 is also just what I was looking for! (Incidently, I did use `AIDL` for a local service; it works!)